# Convert a single color with cvtColor

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a color that I want to convert to a different color space. Is it possible to use `cvtColor` on a `cv::Vec3f` directly without creating a 1x1 `cv::Mat` and populating it with that pixel, using `cvtColor` on the `cv::Mat`, then getting the only pixel out of the output? I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to like getting passed a vector.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    cv::Vec3f hsv;
    hsv[0] = .9;
    hsv[1] = .8;
    hsv[2] = .7;

    std::cout << "HSV: " << hsv << std::endl;

    cv::Vec3b bgr;
    cvtColor(hsv, bgr, CV_HSV2BGR); // OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor

    std::cout << "BGR: " << bgr << std::endl; 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I also tried this, but get a different error:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> hsv(cv::Vec3f(0.7, 0.7, 0.8));

    std::cout << "HSV: " << hsv << std::endl;

    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> bgr;

    cvtColor(hsv, bgr, CV_HSV2BGR); // OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create

    std::cout << "BGR: " << bgr << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @Nacho No, I don't see how that would do the actual conversion here? Could you post code showing how to use it to do a color space conversion?

Comment: Why `cvtColor`? If you only want to convert one vector only, I figure it'd be easier to write a convert function.

Comment: @QuangHoang Because OpenCV already has tons of conversions written. It is usually fairly tricky to implement a color conversion because of all of the wrapping/edge cases, etc.

Comment: @callyalater I have posted the errors on the lines that they occur.

Comment: Your second approach is correct. Just use `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> bgr;` since source and destination must have the same type. Also, you can use `Mat3f` which is a typedef of `Mat_<cv::Vec3f>`

Comment: @Miki It's funny you replied - I was just looking at your profile this morning trying to figure out how to contact you. If you're interested in some contract work, please drop me a note - you can find my email address here: https://github.com/daviddoria

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second approach is correct, but you have source and destination of different types in `cvtColor`, and that causes the error.

Be sure to have both `hsv` and `bgr` of the same type, `CV_32F` here:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat3f hsv(cv::Vec3f(0.7, 0.7, 0.8));

    std::cout << "HSV: " << hsv << std::endl;

    cv::Mat3f bgr;
    cvtColor(hsv, bgr, CV_HSV2BGR); 

    std::cout << "BGR: " << bgr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

You can use `Mat3f` for brevity. It's just a typedef:

```
typedef Mat_<Vec3f> Mat3f;
```

Comment: Is this allocating memory for 'hsv'? That is, say I already have a `cv::Vec3f` and I want to pass it to cvtColor. If I do `cv::Mat3f hsv(myVec)` will this slow down an inner loop?

Comment: Yes, it's deep copying data. Yes, probably will slow down things. Easiest thing is: 1) don't use cvtColor, but apply directly the color conversion, 2) if you have a loop, you probably have a lot of `Vec3f`. You can make a matrix and pass the whole matrix without the loop

Comment: 1) You mean write it myself? Or is there a more direct way to call OpenCV's implementations? 2) I actually have an image, but I don't have enough memory to convert it to float (HSV) on a mobile device. Hence I was doing the conversions and my operations pixel-at-a-time so I could start with an 8bit image and end with a 8bit image and never actually need to construct the 32bit image.

Comment: 1) Yes. You can just _borrow_ OpenCV implementation looking into `color.cpp`. AFAIK, if you want to use `cvtColor` you need a `Mat` or a `std::vector` object. 2) If you can show some code to get the idea we can look for an efficient way

Comment: Here's a follow up question that also basically demonstrates what I'm doing (just this in a loop over a whole image full of pixels): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737942/bgr-to-hsv-and-back-again - Any thoughts on this one? We really should try to get the documentation updated (it only has the forward ranges: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#void%20cvtColor%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn%29)

Comment: It seems that you're mixing range [0,1] for floats and range [0,255] for uchars. Also static cast seems wrong. I'll check better tomorrow ;D

Comment: Hm the static_cast actually seems to work as I'd expect (at least in a stand alone example I setup). Also, I am intentionally trying to convert the uchar BGR values to float HSV, as it seems uchar HSV loses some precision (representing S and V as an integer fraction of 255 cannot represent the full range of float values that are actually computed).

Comment: Yep, static_cast works ok since OpenCV provides conversions operators between Vec of different types. I posted an answer there, now it seems to work as expected. I'll let you know about the email ;D

Comment: **Warning**: even though all you want is to convert a _single_ color into another colorspace, **`OpenCV::cvtColor` will take about 0.1 seconds.** Beware of that.