# BGR to HSV and back again

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

The documentation does not seem to explain what the expected range of the input is for an HSV->BGR conversion. Here is some example code where I am trying to get back the original BGR value after converting it to HSV. Does anyone know which scaling is expected?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Vec3b HSVtoBGR(const cv::Vec3f& hsv)
{
    cv::Vec3f hsvAdjusted = hsv; // If we use this directly, the output is (0,0,1) which is very wrong
    //hsvAdjusted[0] *= 360.; // If we do this to bring all of the values into the range (0,1), the output is (0,1,0), which is also very wrong

    // If we do this to bring all of the values into the range (0,255), the output is (0,0,200), which is still very wrong
    hsvAdjusted[1] *= 255./360.;
    hsvAdjusted[1] *= 255.;
    hsvAdjusted[2] *= 255.;

    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> hsvMat(hsvAdjusted);

    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> bgrMat;

    cv::cvtColor(hsvMat, bgrMat, CV_HSV2BGR);

    cv::Vec3b bgr = static_cast<cv::Vec3b>(bgrMat(0,0));
    return bgr;
}

/** Input 0 <= B <= 255, 0 <= G <= 255, 0 <= R <= 255
  * Output 0 <= H <= 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 1  */
cv::Vec3f BGRtoHSV(const cv::Vec3b& bgr)
{
    cv::Mat3f bgrMat(static_cast<cv::Vec3f>(bgr));

    bgrMat *= 1./255.;

    cv::Mat3f hsvMat;
    cv::cvtColor(bgrMat, hsvMat, CV_BGR2HSV);

    cv::Vec3f hsv = hsvMat(0,0);

    return hsv;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a BGR color
    cv::Vec3b bgr(5, 100, 200);
    std::cout << "bgr: " << bgr << std::endl;

    // Convert BGR to HSV
    cv::Vec3f hsv = BGRtoHSV(bgr);
    std::cout << "hsv: " << hsv << std::endl; // outputs // (29.23, .976, .7843), which seems correct

    // Convert back from HSV to BGR
    cv::Vec3b bgr2 = HSVtoBGR(hsv);
    std::cout << "bgr2: " << bgr2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some scaling problems in the function `HSVtoBGR`.

You need to multiply by 255 the result after the conversion, not before. Remember that different conversions take place for `Mat` of type `CV_32F` and `CV_8U`.

This should work as expected:

```
cv::Vec3b HSVtoBGR(const cv::Vec3f& hsv)
{
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> hsvMat(hsv);
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> bgrMat;

    cv::cvtColor(hsvMat, bgrMat, CV_HSV2BGR);

    bgrMat *= 255; // Upscale after conversion

    // Conversion to Vec3b is handled by OpenCV, no need to static_cast
    return bgrMat(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the code below separately. You'll be able to control the RGB values and get the corresponding HSV scaling.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

char RGB_window[30] = "RGB Window";
char HSV_window[30] = "HSV Window";
 Mat src,hsv;

 static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ){
 Mat image=src.clone();
 Vec3b rgb=image.at<Vec3b>(y,x);
 int B=rgb.val[0];
 int G=rgb.val[1];
 int R=rgb.val[2];

  Mat HSV;
  Mat RGB=image(Rect(x,y,1,1));//capture that pixel in its own ROI
  cvtColor(RGB, HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);

    Vec3b hsv=HSV.at<Vec3b>(0,0);
    int H=hsv.val[0];
    int S=hsv.val[1];
    int V=hsv.val[2];

    char name[30];
    sprintf(name,"B=%d",B);
    putText(image,name, Point(150,40) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"G=%d",G);
    putText(image,name, Point(150,80) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"R=%d",R);
    putText(image,name, Point(150,120) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"H=%d",H);
    putText(image,name, Point(25,40) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"S=%d",S);
    putText(image,name, Point(25,80) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"V=%d",V);
    putText(image,name, Point(25,120) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"X=%d",x);
    putText(image,name, Point(25,300) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,0,255), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"Y=%d",y);
    putText(image,name, Point(25,340) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,0,255), 2,8,false );
    //namedWindow("Ref HSV",WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Mat ref(50,50,CV_8UC3,Scalar(H,S,V));
 //imwrite("hsv.jpg",image);
 imshow( RGB_window, image );
 //imshow( "Ref HSV",ref);

}



int main()

{
//VideoCapture cap(0);
static int Bs=0,Gs=0,Rs=0;
namedWindow("colourCtrl");
 //src = imread("bgr.png",1);
for(;;)
{
  //cap>>src;
  createTrackbar("B","colourCtrl",&Bs,255);
  createTrackbar("G","colourCtrl",&Gs,255);
  createTrackbar("R","colourCtrl",&Rs,255);
  Mat refRGB(500,500,CV_8UC3,Scalar(Bs,Gs,Rs));
  src=refRGB;
  cvtColor(src,hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
  imshow(RGB_window,src);
 imshow(HSV_window,hsv);
 setMouseCallback( RGB_window, onMouse, 0 );
 setMouseCallback( HSV_window, onMouse, 0 );
 char c=waitKey(10);
 if(c=='b')
    {break;}
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue here is not how to get the HSV from the BGR, but how to get a HSV as float values from BGR as uchar values, and back. The problem is with scaling, since different conversions take place for uchar and float values.

Comment: In an HSV pixel, the 24 bits are allocated as H,S,V, in that order. V will be the maximum of (B,G,R), so it will be returned as a uchar. Converting the S uchar value to float and dividing it by 255, will return the S float value. H=30*V*([(R-G)]/[max(B,G,R)-min(B,G,R)] + 4) when B value is maximum.

Comment: It's actually much simpler than that. See my answer ;D