# Convert one pixel from color space to another

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I convert just one pixel from from one color space to another? I figured out that `cv::cvtColor` does not accept `cv::Scalar` neither `cv::Vec3f`. Or in other words, it accepts them but raise an error since they are going to be processed as 1-Channel `cv::Mat` at the end. Is there a better (cleaner like directly from `cv::Scalar` or `cv::VecYX`) way than constructing a one element `cv::Mat` like this?

```
cv::Vec3b covert_1_pixel_to_lab(cv::Vec3b const& src){
    cv::Vec3b src(b,g,r);
    cv::Mat src_mat(1, 1, CV_8UC3);
    src_mat.ptr<uchar>(0)[0] = src(0);
    src_mat.ptr<uchar>(0)[1] = src(1);
    src_mat.ptr<uchar>(0)[2] = src(2);
    cv::Mat dst_mat;
    cv::cvtColor(src_mat, dst_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);
    return cv::Vec3b(dst_mat.ptr<uchar>(0)[0],
        dst_mat.ptr<uchar>(0)[1],
        dst_mat.ptr<uchar>(0)[2]);
}
```

Comment: Before marking as a dupe, check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35737032/5008845) helps

Comment: Short answer, no... (AFAIK) ;D

Comment: @miki I swear I searched million time but did not find that question :D. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROI via Rects:

```
Rect r=Rect(x,y,1,1);
Mat img2=img(r);
cvtColor(img2,img2,CV_BGR2Luv);//or any other color space
```

This may make the change on img as well

Comment: Thanks but I have the value as cv::Vec3b not as cv::Mat.. It is not part of any image