# Different results between self-made bgr2hsv and opencv bgr2hsv

Tags: c++, opencv, color-space

I implemented bgr2hsv function by accessing pixels with OpenCV, C++.
I just coded it with bgr2hsv algorithm on the Internet.
And I compared my `bgr2hsv()` to `cvtColor()` results.

Actually, result images has a little different colors even though the original image was same. I tried to see why different but I couldn't find it.
Could you see the source codes and result images?
Here's the code.

```
//self-made bgr2hsv
double b, g, r;
double bb, gg, rr;
double tmax, tmin;
double h = 0, s = 0, v = 0;
double del, delB, delG, delR;

Mat image = imread("lena.jpg", 1);
Mat clone1 = image.clone();
Mat img;
image.convertTo(img, CV_64F);

for (int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++)
    {
        b = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0];
        g = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
        r = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2];

        bb = b / 255;
        gg = g / 255;
        rr = r / 255;

        tmax = _max(bb, gg, rr);
        tmin = _min(bb, gg, rr);

        v = tmax;
        del = tmax - tmin;
        if (del == 0) {
            h = 0;
            s = 0;
        }
        else {
            s = del / tmax;
            delB = ((tmax - b) / 6 + del / 2) / del;
            delG = ((tmax - g) / 6 + del / 2) / del;
            delR = ((tmax - r) / 6 + del / 2) / del;

            if (b == tmax) {
                h = (2 / 3) + delG - delR;
            }
            if (g == tmax) {
                h = (1 / 3) + delR - delB;
            }
            if (r == tmax) {
                h = delB - delG;
            }
            if (h < 0) h += 1;
            if (h > 1) h -= 1;
        }
        img.at<Vec3d>(y, x)[0] = h;
        img.at<Vec3d>(y, x)[1] = s;
        img.at<Vec3d>(y, x)[2] = v;
    }
}
//bgr2hsv with cvtColor
cvtColor(image,clone1,CV_BGR2HSV);

imwrite("implemented_hsv.jpg",clone1);
imwrite("bgr2hsv.jpg", img);

//show images
imshow("bgr2hsv", img);
imshow("implemented_hsv",clone1);
waitKey(0);
```

And results are here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mrP2.jpg)

Comment: You may also consult the [OpenCV Source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L4476)

Comment: Thanks. I'll also read your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest grabbing something from the internet and expecting it to give you the correct result unless you understand what's going on. Instead of using this, why not just use [the formula from the OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html)?

For an example of this particular conversion, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896166/converting-a-single-bgr-color-with-cvtcolor-and-using-the-result-to-extract-that/44896475#44896475). It uses the exact formula OpenCV mentions in the docs linked above for BGR to HSV conversion. It's in Python and not C++, but Python is fairly easy to read anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I didn't even come up with studying opencv docs directly. It's my shame. :( Next time I have a question, I would read and study. official docs before inquiring. I'll check your links and codes.

Comment: @JungraeCho no problem. The docs for OpenCV are really good sometimes, and really lacking other times. With standard functions like this, they're super helpful.