# Map a pixel color found in OpenCV to a pre-determined list of colors

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors

I have a scenario where I have obtained one or more colors from an image, but now I need to determine which one of my existing color options it is closest to.

For example, I may have red(255,0,0), green(0,255,0) and blue(0,0,255) as my three choices, but the image may contain orange(255,165,0).

What I need then is a way to determine which one of those three values I should choose as my output color to replace orange.

One approach I have considered is to measure the range from those three values and see which one is the smallest & select that color.

Example:

**orange -> red**

```
abs(255 - 255) = 0, abs(165 - 0) = 165, abs(0 - 0) = 0 
0 + 165 + 0 = 165
```

**orange -> green**

```
abs(255 - 0) = 255, abs(165 - 255) = 90, abs(0 - 0) = 0
255 + 90 + 0 = 345
```

**orange -> blue**

```
abs(255 - 0) = 255, abs(165 - 0) = 165, abs(0 - 255) = 255 
255 + 165 + 255 = 675
```

Under this approach, I would pick red.

However, I am not sure if this is the best, or even a particularly valid, one so was wondering if there is something out there that is more accurate & would scale better to an increased color pallete.

*Update* The reduction answer linked in here does not help as it reduces things across the board. I need the ability to link a broad range of colors to several specific options.

Comment: This is not the correct way of matching color range. A good way of matching color range is to convert it to HSV color space. Provide your code where you achieve these colors and how are you using them, to determine best method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the number of colors in an image with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906693/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-colors-in-an-image-with-opencv)

Comment: @Zindarod Thanks, I suspected I needed to operate in a different color space. I did explore using HSV, but was able to assemble something based off of what Kamil posted using the Delta E algorithm to find the closest match for a color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should represent and compare colors in different color space. I suggest space, that represent human color perception. Therefore L*a*b color space will be the best.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space/

Color distances in that coordinate space are represented by *delta e* value. You could find different standards for *delta e* below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIELAB_Delta_E.2A/

In order to change color space you have to use `cv::cvtColor()` method. Color conversion for single pixel is described below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35737319/8682088/

After calculating pixel coordinates in L*a*b space, you could easily calculate *delta e* and compare colors with any reference and pick the one with the smallest error.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement something just now using your suggestion that properly maps the colors.